# Cant access api data using axios in next js it returns Error: Request failed with status code 429

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I am trying to fetch data from API in next JS  13 and its not working I tried the same API in rapid API studio and it worked  I couldn't figure out what is the error in my code also It happens with all API from rapid API. API like weather api and json placeholder API seems to be working.

```
import axios from "axios";

const getDadJokes = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    "https://example.p.rapidapi.com/random/joke",
    {
      headers: {
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "api-key",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "host-url",
      },
    }
  );

  const data = await response.data;
  return data;
};

const page = async () => {
  const dadJokes = await getDadJokes();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>about</h1>
      <h1>{dadJokes.body.punchline}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

Comment: the code seems fine, maybe that's a CORS related issue? u could try with a server-side proxy

Comment: can you tell me how to do that i am new to next js

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have exceeded your request limit, maybe nothing wrong with nextjs.

`You have exceeded the DAILY quota for Random Jokes on your current plan, BASIC. Upgrade your plan at https://rapidapi.com/KegenGuyll/api/dad-jokes`

and please hide your api key, don't share sensitive information in public.

Comment: no matter which api i use i am getting this issue btw i tested the api in rapid api studio and it gives me 200 ok response in my system i am getting 429

Comment: This is problem with your plan I think. you can upgrade to increase limit or wait for tomorrow to get new daily quota. try with postman or other http client you will get same status code. and in rapid api studio I think they have not limit validation or such. I make assumption this by reading the response message in your api endpoint.